# Synaptic installation problem Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, package-management

I'm not able to install `Synaptic`, please help me.

```
jhon@jhon-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
[sudo] password for jhon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package synaptic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'synaptic' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

Synaptic is available in the `universe` repository. If you're getting this error, than it means you haven't enable it.

To enable it, open `Software & Updates`,
and check the box beside `Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)`

[image]

[image]

Then 
`sudo apt-get update` 
 `sudo apt-get install synaptic`